# Azure DevOps Release pipeline - cannot see self-hosted agent created by another user

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

In my current Azure DevOps project, my colleague has created a self-hosted Ubuntu agent for our pipelines, and in the agent's pipeline permission we have ensured its "Grant access permission to all pipelines" field is enabled.

I am in the process of setting-up our Release pipeline. In the Release pipeline, Add an agent job, Agent pool selection dropdown, I cannot see the self-hosted agent created by my colleague.

And so I wonder if it's because the owner of the self-hosted agent is my colleague and therefore I cannot see the self-hosted agent from the dropdown?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, you can check if your account has the **User or higher level** role in the **Target Agent Pool -> Security**.

[image]

Here is the doc about [About pipeline security roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-security-roles?view=azure-devops)